# Centering a header image

Tags: css, center

I'm fairly new to CSS coding. I'm attempting to center an image and cannot get it to center. From what I know, the relevant code is as follows:

*The CSS Code:*

```
 #header img {
    align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

*The code as it is on the HTML file:*

```
<div id="header">
<a href="$settings[shopurl]">
<img src="https://capa.lunarmania.com:2083/cpsess1188922546/viewer/home%2famysp0%2fpublic_html%2fimages/AmyPromos.png" border="0" align="center" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
```

I feel as though I'm missing something but I cannot find it or figure it out. Any help at all is appreciated. The image sits stubbornly on the top left of the webpage instead of centering in the header like I ask it to do.

Comment: Check this article on [centering things](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) with CSS.  Has a section on images.  The img align tag is deprecated in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems. First, it's `text-align`, not `align`.

Centering things in CSS sometimes isn't as simple as setting `text-align: center`. Sometimes, you'll have a block-level element which is as large as its contents; in this case, if your div is as big as the image, it won't center the image because centering it in the div won't move it. Make sure that your div is also centered, or that it's as big as the thing inside which you want to center the image.

Also, `text-align: center` affects contents *inside* an element, not the element itself. So, in this case, you want the centering CSS on `#header`, not just the image.

Finally, if you want to physically center an element by itself, it needs to be a block-level element (i.e. `display: block`, which is default for divs) and have an automatic margin on the left and right. This can be achieved by setting `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`, or using a shorthand like `margin: topbottom auto` or `margin: top auto bottom`.

In this particular case, you probably just want to set `text-align: center` on the `#header` element, but in general, "centering an image" is sometimes more complicated than just one line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to center the text inside your #header rather than center the image.  Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/10py5mu6/

```
#header {
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```